# hawtio RSS Feed like old activemq console

Tags: rss, activemq-classic, hawtio, web-console

Do you know if there is a similar way to have a RSS Feed for a specific activeMQ queue in Hawtio like in the old web console? If not, is there a wish list for future features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no such functionality.

You can log a ticket in the hawtio issue tracker at https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Claus Ibsen,

I followed your advice and a [ticket](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1147) for it is opened.